# Cylinder top and bottom in openGL

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

My problem is that I've made a cylinder with openGL in C++ and I don't know how to add a top and a bottom to it. I wrote this function:

```
glm::vec3   CMyApp::GetUV(float u, float v)
{
    float r = 0.5; //radius
    float h = 2; //heigh

    u *= 2*3.1415f;
    v *= h;
    float cu = cosf(u), su = sinf(u), cv = cosf(v), sv = sinf(v);

    return glm::vec3( r*cu, v, -r*su );
}
```

the code above makes the cylinder.

```
bool CMyApp::Init()
{
    Vertex vert[(N+1)*(M+1)];
    for (int i=0; i<=N; ++i)
        for (int j=0; j<=M; ++j)
        {
          float u = i/(float)N;
          float v = j/(float)M;

            vert[i + j*(N+1)].p = GetUV(u, v);
            vert[i + j*(N+1)].c = glm::normalize( vert[i + j*(N+1)].p );
        }

GLushort indices[3*2*(N)*(M)];
for (int i=0; i<N; ++i)
    for (int j=0; j<M; ++j)
    {
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 0] = (i)      + (j)*  (N+1);
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 1] = (i+1)    + (j)*  (N+1);
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 2] = (i)      + (j+1)*(N+1);
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 3] = (i+1)    + (j)*  (N+1);
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 4] = (i+1)    + (j+1)*(N+1);
        indices[6*i + j*3*2*(N) + 5] = (i)      + (j+1)*(N+1);
    }
```

With this code it will only show an opened cylinder. How to modify this code? 
Thank you in advance

Comment: The top and the bottom of cylinder are circular polygons. Arrange triangles around the center point of a circle. One point of the triangles is the center point, the other 2 points are at the circle.